# Talking to you vs By talking to you

Tags: meaning

What is the difference in the meaning between following sentences which BBC learning English is saying like this:

> Note from the above examples that the -ing form participle is used to talk about past, as well as present events, e.g.:
>
> Talking to you I always feel that my problems will be solved.
>
> By talking to you, I always feel that my problems will be solved.

Source: http://www.bbc.co.uk/worldservice/learningenglish/grammar/learnit/learnitv305.shtml

Comment: The definition of *by* being used here is ["through the agency, efficacy, work, participation, or authority of" (#11)](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/by)

Answer (score 1):

The first says that you get the feeling, while talking to the person, that your problems will be solved.

The second says talking to the person gives you the feeling that your problems will be solved.

The phrase **I always feel** complicates the meaning of these sentences. The initial phrase modifies **feel**, but speakers might be wanting to say that the talking does the solving.

Comment: TRomano,I haven't got you yet. But BBC is saying differently which I haven't understood

Comment: "By talking to you, my problems will be solved" is not the same as "By talking to you *I feel* my problems will be solved"  and "Talking to you my problems will be solved" is not the same as "Talking to you *I feel* my problems will be solved".